# Linux: execute command on each copied file

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, file-transfer

What is the best way to copy files to a new location while executing a command on each copied file? The copied folder(s) is expected to have sub-directories.

For example, you could be doing a `cp -R` to a share or `rsync` for backup and you want to:

- reencode videos: `ffmpeg -i $source -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy $destination`
- compress for archival: `gzip -9 $source`
- encrypt for transport: `gpg -e -r USER@example.com $source`
- only copy headers for preview: `head -n 10 $source > $destination`
- or even chain multiple commands

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to copy the directory structure:

```
sdir="/path/to/source/dir"
tdir="/path/to/target/dir"
cd "$sdir"
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p "$tdir"/{} \;
```

There may be more you want to do, e.g. copy permissions:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod --reference={} "$tdir"/{} \;
```

(Note: `--reference` is not required by POSIX).

Or instead of `mkdir` you may use `cp -a --attributes-only` (also non-POSIX):

```
# this assumes $tdir doesn't yet exist but its future parent does
cp -a "$sdir" "$tdir"
```

then remove all non-directories from `$tdir`, leaving bare directory structure:

```
# make sure "$tdir" is what it should be
find "$tdir" ! -type d -delete
```

Now, when you have the target directory structure, work with the files. If you don't need pipes, redirections etc., this example approach will do:

```
cd "$sdir"
find . -type f -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy "$tdir"/{} \;
#                       source ^^                         target ^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you do need pipes or redirections, you will need a shell to handle them:

```
cd "$sdir"
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'head -n 10 "$1" >"$2"/"$1"' sh-find     {}    "$tdir" \;
#                                  for sh these are  $0:^^^^^^^, $1:^^, $2:^^^^^
```

Running a separate shell for every file is slow, but it allows you to do virtually anything.